# is support blockhound for cucumber & coroutine?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, cucumber, blockhound

I have some trouble using cucumber & kotlin croutine.

```
    @Given("clean")
    fun clean() {
        BlockHound.install()
        runBlocking {
            Thread.sleep(100L)
        }
    }
```

when I install blockhound and run sleep method in runBlock scope but nothing happened.

My environment is

- springboot 2.5.5
- java 11
- kotlin 1.5.31
- cucumbe, cucumber-junit-platform-engine 7.0.0

how I run blockhound in my test method?
thank you. :)

Comment: I haven’t used BlockHound, but the Kotlin Coroutines Debug library contains BlockHound configuration. https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-debug/index.html

Comment: thankyou @Tenfour04 

`org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-debug:1.4.0` is good to me :)